How to skip an element in a JsonArray, when the parsing of that element fails?
Below is the default code to parse a JsonArray, which works totally fine if there is of course no error or typo in the Json string:
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public required string Name { get; set; }
}

Program code:
var jsonString = @"
[ 
    { ""Id"": 1, ""Name"": ""name1"" },
    { ""Id"": 2, ""Name"": ""name2"" },
    { ""Id"": 3, ""NameX"": ""name3"" },
    { ""Id"": 4, ""Name"": ""name4"" },
    { ""Id"": 5, ""Name"": ""name5"" }
]
";

List<Person> people = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<Person>>(jsonString) ?? [];
    
Console.WriteLine(people.Count);

But notice that in the jsonString, there is unfortunately a typo.
Of course, this results in a runtime error. It is possible to wrap the Deserialize<> in a try-catch, but then I have 0 people in my people array.
This is a simplification of the situation I have of course, in my case I get the json from an external source. (Assume it is not possible to skip the required attribute for string Name in this example)
How can I change this code so that I basically have a TryDeserialize<>? I would like to parse every correct object, and skip (and log if that is possible) all the objects that aren't correct? So that my final people array has 4 people in it (ids 1,2,4,5)?

"but then I have 0 people in my people array" - Yes. Your input data is corrupt. "Smart fixing" it is often dangerous. Wouldn't you rather know and get your input fixed rather than work on incomplete data?

I know, that's why I would like the logging part :) But I don't think it is desirable that 4 of the 5 people cannot be parsed, because of 1 wrong element in it. The other elements should not be affected by the wrong element.

Should Idx also be treated as a typo? And 5x?

Check JsonSerializerOptions.UnmappedMemberHandling : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializeroptions.unmappedmemberhandling?view=net-8.0#system-text-json-jsonserializeroptions-unmappedmemberhandling

When requirement is strange, then it may be XY problem. Json is typically used to store/transfer data, where values may be invalid, but structure is normally known. How can such error in json occurs in a first place? Who and how produces the json?

^^ Exactly why I would strongly advise against skip-reading. If there is a typo in the structure then the producer has a systematic problem/error. And it should be fixed there. Now: If there was an error in the structure, how can you possibly trust the values to be correct?

Maybe Name should not be required.

Just a thought: If this is inherent behavior of your system, maybe consider Line-JSON. Then one invalid row doesn't invalidate all data.

@Sinatr, json is coming from a cosmos database container. And a Cosmos document can be any form of key/value pairs. A lot of entries will be picked up, but if someone modifies or duplicates the content of one of the entries, and there is 1 small typo, then no entries can be read from the container anymore.
This should be handled at the frontside, but still I want it to be safe at my side as well.

You are making self safe in a very doubtful way - by skipping entry, exactly Y problem to which you have answers now. But X problem still, you won't get any entry for certain ID. Sure you or user may figure the problem later, using logs, eyes, or even automated error message.. but why bother? Fail fast, refuse import of invalid data. Simple.

For such task you would need to implement custom JSON converter (inheriting from JsonConverter) for list of Person objects.
Here's example implementation:
public class ListPfPeopleJsonConverter : JsonConverter<List<Person>>
{
    public override List<Person>? Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        var people = new List<Person>();
        reader.Read();

        while (reader.TokenType == JsonTokenType.StartObject)
        {
            if(TryReadPerson(ref reader, out var person))
            {
                people.Add(person);
            }
        }

        return people;
    }

    private static bool TryReadPerson(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, out Person person)
    {
        person = null;
        try
        {
            person = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Person>(ref reader);
            return true;
        }
        catch
        {
            ConsumeJsonObject(ref reader);
            return false;
        }
        finally
        {
            // Move to next item.
            reader.Read();
        }
    }

    private static void ConsumeJsonObject(ref Utf8JsonReader reader)
    {
        // Consume invalid item to the "end of object"
        while (reader.TokenType != JsonTokenType.EndObject)
        {
            reader.Read();
        }
    }

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, List<Person> value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

And then the usage:
var jsonString = @"
    [ 
        { ""Id"": 1, ""Name"": ""name1"" },
        { ""Id"": 2, ""Name"": ""name2"" },
        { ""Id"": 3, ""NameX"": ""name3"" },
        { ""Id"": 4, ""Name"": ""name4"" },
        { ""Id"": 5, ""Name"": ""name5"" }
    ]
    ";

var options = new JsonSerializerOptions();
options.Converters.Add(new ListPfPeopleJsonConverter());

List<Person> people = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<Person>>(jsonString, options) ?? [];

Console.WriteLine(people.Count);


One option would be to use a JsonReader instead.
The code will also skip entries where Id is missing rather then setting it to 0.
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var jsonString = @"
    [ 
        { ""Id"": 1, ""Name"": ""name1"" },
        { ""Id"": 2, ""Name"": ""name2"" },
        { ""Id"": 3, ""NameX"": ""name3"" },
        { ""Id"": 4, ""Name"": ""name4"" },
        { ""Id"": 5, ""Name"": ""name5"" },
        { ""IdX"": 1, ""Name"": ""name6"" }
    ]
";

    List<Person> people = new List<Person>();
    var reader = new Utf8JsonReader(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonString));

    while (reader.Read())
    {
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonTokenType.StartObject)
        {
            int? id = null;
            string? name = null;

            while (reader.Read() && reader.TokenType != JsonTokenType.EndObject)
            {
                if (reader.TokenType == JsonTokenType.PropertyName)
                {
                    string? propertyName = reader.GetString();
                    reader.Read();

                    if (propertyName == "Id")
                        id = reader.GetInt32();
                    else if (propertyName == "Name")
                        name = reader.GetString();
                }
            }

            if (name != null && id != null)
                people.Add(new Person { Id = id.Value, Name = name });
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine(people.Count);
}

public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public required string Name { get; set; }
}


A rather simple (but probably also quite inefficient!) workaround if you just want to discard Persons with invalid structure could be deserializing to a generic JsonElement first. Then iterate over this resulting element and try to parse each entry into a Person. If deserializing to a Person works, add it to the resulting list. If it throws an exception, just ignore the exception and continue with the next element.
JsonElement a = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<JsonElement>(jsonString);
List<Person> l = new List<Person>();
foreach (var o in a.EnumerateArray()) {
  try { 
    Person p = o.Deserialize<Person>();
    l.Add(p);
  }
  catch {}
}

This approach avoids the need for a custom converter. But it's probably of limited use in nested structures, when you want to ignore erroneous elements within nested lists. Also I assume this to be rather slow, compared to a custom converter.
See also this fiddle for a working example.
